# Cloning an element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, nodes

I have a `li element` parented to a `div` with `id` `holder`. I need to clone the `li` multiple times, have all the clones parented to the `holder div` and change their `data-ids`. My hierarchy looks like this:

```
<div id="holder">
    <li data-id=0 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
</div>
```

How can I clone the `li element` and than change it's `data-id` so I get:

```
<div id="holder">
    <li data-id=0 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
    <li data-id=1 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
    <li data-id=2 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
    <li data-id=3 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
    <li data-id=4 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
    <li data-id=5 class="element">
        //other nodes
    </li>
</div>
```

-- David

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use the .clone jQuery function but it did not want to work.

Comment: Note that [`li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) are only valid children of `ol`, `ul`, and `menu` elements, not `div`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
var holder, li, clone, counter;
holder = $("#holder");
li = holder.find("li:first");
counter;
for (counter = 1; counter <= 5; ++counter) {
    clone = li.clone();
    clone.attr("data-id", counter);
    clone.appendTo(holder);
}
```

Comment: if number on childs is about 5 it may be ok, but with a larger number it better to generate ALL the markup in cycle and then add in to DOM at once

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Epzt9/7/

Also - and I'm surprised no-one else has mentioned this - your containing element for the list items should be a `<ul>`, not a `<div>` - `<li>` tags don't stand on their own, they should belong to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
var clone = $("#holder > li").last().clone();
clone.data("id", parseInt(clone.data("id"), 10) + 1);
$("#holder").append(clone);
```

It gets a reference to the last `li` child of `#holder` and [clones](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) that. It then adds 1 to the current value of the `data-id` attribute, and appends the clone back into `#holder`.

However, this won't actually change the value of the attribute on the element (if you inspected the DOM, clones would appear to have the same `data-id` value as the element from which they came). The new value is associated with the element, which is fine if you are using the jQuery `data` method to obtain this value later. If not, you would need to use `attr` instead of `data` to set the value.