# Capture the event after a section element has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have a div that contains sections:

```
<div class="Placeafterthis">
</div>
...
<div class="k-content">
<section class="rbs-section" id="id1" name="">
.. // section content
</section>
<section class="rbs-section" id="id2" name="">
.. // section content
</section>
<section class="rbs-section" id="id3" name="">
.. // section content
</section>
</div>
```

Now basically these sections are loaded when the DOM is ready. Is there a way I could check when a particular section has finished loading? Once its finished loading I need to clone that section and place it just after the "Placeafterthis" div. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: How do you bind content to those divs? Did you use some ajax call, angular ?

Comment: I'm not doing the binding. That has already been done. I'd just like to get the ready or loaded event of the section.

Comment: What type of content is in the sections, images, iframes ?

Comment: how do sections loading? show us some js magic to help find answer

Comment: content in sections are just buttons and grid list controls and they are loaded through Kendo UI. Grid List: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Comment: are there any events bound to your _to be cloned_ elements?

Comment: Yes there are events and animations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when nodes are added to `.k-content`, [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) them using jQuery, and append them after `.Placeafterthis` ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/wew30u73/4/)):

```
var kContent = $('.k-content'); // the original container in which the items will be placed
var $Placeafterthis = $('.Placeafterthis'); // the cloned elements target marker placeholder

function mutationHandler(mutation) { // the mutation handler will deal with the addition of new nodes to the original container
    var addedNodes = mutation.addedNodes;

    if (!addedNodes.length) { // if no added nodes return
        return;
    }

    $.each(addedNodes, function () { // iterate the add nodes
        var $element = $(this);

        if (!$element.hasClass('rbs-section')) { // if the node doesn't have the right class continue to the next one
            return true;
        }

        var $prevSections = $Placeafterthis.find('~ .rbs-section'); // find if there are already sections append to the target
        var $target = $prevSections.length === 0 ? $Placeafterthis : $prevSections.last(); // if there are sections take the last, if not use the marker

        /** note that using .clone(true) will also clone all jQuery event handlers and data from the original element. If you don't need this behavior, just use .clone() **/

        $target.after($element.clone(true)); // append after the target
    });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) { // create a new mutation observer
    mutations.forEach(mutationHandler);
});

var config = { // config should include only childList because we just want added nodes 
    childList: true
};

observer.observe(kContent.get(0), config); // watch the original container with the observer
```

Comment: only answer that appears to clone `withDataAndEvents`

Comment: Thinking of it, I'm not sure that's the requested behavior. I'll add a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I got the cloning code from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126873/cloning-an-element-multiple-times) and modified as needed. Using the `async`on the last `script` tag always works for me, but use it on an external script, I just did it inline for demonstration purposes. Most importantly the script is at the closing body tag to avoid blocking. Attached an event listener on the DOMContentLoaded event, that's when the sections should be ready (unless there's iframes in the sections...). I colored all of the elements' borders for easy viewing.

**UPDATE:** After reading guest271314's post, it reminded me that I neglected to consider the clone's IDs. As clones they'd have identical ids as well, so I refactored it a bit and added a bit of Star Wars.

```css
section[id^="id"] {
  border: 3px solid silver;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}
section[id^="st"] {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}
.kamino-content {
  border: 3px dashed blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.Placeafterthis {
  border: 3px dotted orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Placeafterthis">
  Place After This
</div>

<div class="kamino-content">
  <section class="fett-dna" id="id1" name="jango">
    .. // section content
  </section>
  <section class="fett-dna" id="id2" name="jango">
    .. // section content
  </section>
  <section class="fett-dna" id="id3" name="jango">
    .. // section content
  </section>
  Kamino-Content
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- You should really do this: <script async src="external.js"></script> -->

<script async>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cloneLab, false);

  function cloneLab() {
    var vat = $('.kamino-content'),
      squad = $('.fett-dna').size(),
      fett = vat.find('.fett-dna');
    fett.each(function(idx, val) {
      var trooper = $(this).clone();
      trooper.attr("id", "st" + (squad + idx)).attr("name", "stormtrooper");
      trooper.insertAfter('.Placeafterthis');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `$.get()` , appending response to `.k-content` , filtering `id` of selected `section` element at response to clone , add character to `id` to prevent duplicate `id`'s in `DOM` , insert after `.Placeafterthis` ; define `getSections` set with jQuery promise object as `this` , recursively call `getSections` to return `Array.prototype.shift()` on `sections` array to return `$.get()` for each item at index `0` in order, else if `false` returned by `!!` operator on `section[0]` return `this.promise()`

```
    // `id`s of `section` elements to append to `.k-content`
    var sections = ["#id1", "#id2", "#id3"];
    // selected `id` to do stuff with
    var selected = sections[1];
    // container
    var container = $(".k-content");
    // `complete` handler for `$.get()` requests
    function selectedId(html, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        // decode `data` : `id` sent with request
        var id = decodeURIComponent(this.url.split("?")[1]).split("=")[1];
        // append `section` to `container`
        container.append($(html).filter(id));
        // if `selected` appended to `container` ,
        // and `selected` is not in `DOM` directly after `.Placeafterthis` element
        // clone `selected` , append after `.Placeafterthis` element
        if (container.find(selected).is("*") 
          && !$(".Placeafterthis + " + selected + "-a").is("*")) {
            var clone = $(selected, container).clone()
                        .attr("id", selected.slice(1) + "-a");
            $(".Placeafterthis").after(clone)
        }
    }

    var getSections = function getSections() {
        var p = sections.shift();
        return !!sections 
               && $.get("http://fiddle.jshell.net/guest271314/rvt8evoy/show/"
               , {"id": p}, selectedId).then(getSections)
    };

    getSections()
    .then(function() {
      console.log("complete")
    })
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1d6vmdpt/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you will place your script after the last section:

```
<section class="rbs-section" id="id3" name="">
.. // section content
</section>

<script>
  (function() {
    var s3 = document.getElementById("id3");
    ...
  })();
</script>
```

then it will be invoked exactly after that element and its predecessors will appear in the DOM.